# Change calculator nickels pennies

Tags: python

Project: Create a Python code with the inputs `nickels`, `pennies`, `sum` and returns if it is possible to create that `sum` with that number of `nickels` and `pennies`.

My code is:

```
def corect_change(nickles, pennies, summ):
    result = False
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i <= nickles:
        if summ == i * 5:
            result = True
        else:
            while j <= pennies:
                if summ == (i * 5) + j:
                    result = True
                j += 1
        i += 1
    return result

print corect_change(5,3,11)
```

Now this works for sums divisible by 5 but fails when it has to include pennies.

Can someone show me why and give me some ideas for improving it.

Comment: What's the simplest input it fails for? What's the simplest input it doesn't fail for? What are the outputs?

Comment: Why don't you simply use basic math? You could just return whether the sum of all nickles and pennies by its currency value equal to the expected value, i.e. `return nickles * 5 + pennies == summ`, assuming `summ` (name for the sum as per your function definition, good on you for not using a reserved function name) is in cents.

Comment: You start your loop with i = 1, so you always assume one nickle into the sum.  You should probably be counting from 0 nickles, etc.

Comment: @metatoaster
But wouldn't that just show if the total of all the coins equals the sum, not if the sum can be made from some of the coins.
Thanks

Comment: @swstephe
Good point, just changed that. Thank you.

Comment: You made some edits after Harvey answered; note that as currently written, one big issue is that you don't reset j each time in the outer loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems with your code:

- it always assumes that there is at least one nickel available
- it always assumes that summ > 5, because `i` starts at 1
- you use up your pennies before using up nickels

Here's a couple of implementations based on using as many nickels as possible first, and then pennies.

```
def correct_change2(nickels, pennies, sum):
    # While you have nickels left and sum is still more than 5 cents...
    while sum > 5 and nickels:
        sum -= 5
        nickels -= 1
    # You've removed as many nickels as you had or sum is now less than 5
    # If you have enough pennies left, return True
    return pennies >= sum

def correct_change(nickels, pennies, sum):
    # Remove as many nickels as you have or as many as sum needs,
    # whichever is less
    sum -= 5 * min(nickels, sum / 5)
    # You're out of nickels or sum is less than 5
    # If you have enough pennies to equal sum, return True
    return pennies >= sum

print correct_change(5,3,11)
```

Also, here's your method lightly rearranged to work:

```
def corect_change(nickles, pennies, summ):
    i = 0
    while i <= nickles:
        if summ - (i * 5) < 5:
            break
        i += 1
    j = 0
    while j <= pennies:
        if summ == (i * 5) + j:
            break
        j += 1
    return summ == (i * 5) + j
```

but we can make that more Python idiomatic by using for loops and `xrange()`:

```
def corect_change(nickles, pennies, summ):
    for i in xrange(nickles):
        if summ - (i * 5) < 5:
            break
    for j in xrange(pennies):
        if summ == (i * 5) + j:
            break
    return summ == (i * 5) + j
```

Comment: This looks great and runs perfectly.
Can you just explain how the min() function works that you've used.

Comment: Did you understand my comment about how you were using up pennies first? That's not how you'd make change in real life. Also, counting up like you did makes the problem a little harder than removing from `summ`. Please accept the answer.

Comment: `min()` gives you the lowest value of the two that are passed in, so `min(5,6)` will be `5`. It is used here to calculate the minimum of the number of nickels that are needed to get as close as possible to the sum, and the number that you have. e.g. if you are trying to get to a sum of 64, you would like to use 12 nickels, but if you only have 11, you will calculate 11*5=55, and reduce the sum by 55 leaving 9. If you have at least 9 pennies you can make the change. If you were trying to get to 54 you would only use 10 nickels in that case, hence the `min`.

Comment: @Galax Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Harvey Yer, I can see that taking away from sum is allot simpler that the way I was doing it. Thanks for the answer.